# What is the structure of automorphisms of $2 \times 2$ matrix rings over the set of integers?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, ring-theory

Actually, my question is more general than what the title asks. But for brevity, I begin with a more approachable problem. Suppose that $f \colon \operatorname{M}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is an automorphism. Then we can see that

$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}\right) = a f(e_{11}) + b f(e_{12}) + c f(e_{21}) + d f(e_{22}),$$

where $e_{ij}$ are matrix units. Lets call them $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \theta$ respectively. Then we get

$$f \left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix} \right) = a \alpha + b \beta + c \gamma + d \theta.$$

Now we can see that

$\alpha = f(e_{11}) = f(e_{12} e_{21}) = f(e_{12})f(e_{21}) = \beta \gamma.$

Similarly, we can see that

$\theta = \gamma \beta\\
\beta = \alpha \beta = \beta \gamma \beta\\
\gamma = \theta \gamma = \gamma \beta \gamma.$

How can I go further from here? I've tried several approaches, but I couldn't get more refined arguments. What if $f$ is inner? I have read that all automorphisms are inner here, but I don't know how to get to that conclusion.

My actual problem is with arbitrary rings, say R and S. What is the structure of homomorphisms between $\operatorname{M}_n(R)$ and $\operatorname{M}_n(S)$? I don't know about the hardness of this question, but any hint or resource would suffice to proceed.

Comment: You mean $e_{ij}$, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: Over a field, we have Skolem-Noether, so every automorphism of $M_n(K)$ is inner, but in general this is not true for $M_n(R)$. Then the structure of the quotient group $Aut(M_n(R))/Inn(M_n(R))$ can be described, see for example the paper by [Isaacs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGr6Siir79AhUD_CoKHYAHB-oQFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2F0024379580902219%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3D91163836d28cbc7ffd05467a268341f9%26pid%3D1-s2.0-0024379580902219-main.pdf&usg=AOvVaw07SSOeTcTzMCRtMB9xE4oJ).

Comment: If ring $R$ has non-trivial automorphism $\sigma$, then the automorphism of $M_n(R)$ sending each entry of a matrix to its image under $\sigma$ is usually not inner. Note that the automorphism given above is **not $R$-linear**.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The paper you gave above talks about automorphisms as an **$R$-algebra**, not a **ring**.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Does the OP not consider automorphisms as an $R$-algebra? This would be more useful, perhaps.